# How to read application insights key during service startup

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

What is the correct way to configure ApplicationInsights instrumentation key so it can be used during service startup (before `IConfiguration` is available), for example

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

            //TODO: how to extract this key from config??
            appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = "I want to pull this key from config";

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                    .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information(Constants.Logging.Messages.SERVICE_STARTED, assembly.Name);
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, Constants.Logging.Messages.SERVICE_STARTED, assembly.Name);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                // make sure all batched messages are written.
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ASP.NET Core's ConfigurationBuilder in a Test Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943484/using-asp-net-cores-configurationbuilder-in-a-test-project)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that didn't help me. The code in Ivan Yangs post below was what I needed.

Comment: It was because that answer was not written within the context of `Main` that it didn't land with me. The answer below was much more useful for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

        //TODO: how to extract this key from config??
        //appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = "I want to pull this key from config";

        //use this code:
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var configuration = builder.Build();

        string myikey = configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey").Value;
        appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = myikey;

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                .CreateLogger();


       //other code

    }
```